# Emailing internal recruiters about updated skills

Tags: interviewing, recruitment, skills, internal-transfer

I applied for a Java script internal position. My first interview turned out to be a little bit technical and interviewer suggested to brush up my skills as I told him my skills are college level but want to move to js world.

2nd round was online test.

But I did a 12 hour online js course and by knowledge is 12 hours mature. I still don't have production quality  knowledge.like but I am more confident. Can I mail the recruiter saying about this. If so how should I phrase this. Seems a bit awkward idea. Should I proceed to ask recruiter.  I have not had interview with hiring manager yet though.

Just for more details:

They are after 2 years experienced developers and I have 3 years in non JS production level development experience. So my question was basically there might have been a disconnect between recruiter and the interviewer who suggested to brush up JS. Since this is an internal position i thought if doing online courses is worth mentioning to recruiter now that I am just waiting on next steps or my saying that if I am making myself silly.

Comment: For College level skills I would expect much more than a 12hr course. A 12hr course is a beginner - and probably if I was recruiting you irrelevant it is nice to know you had a course but not enough experience to be noticeable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're overplaying how far you've come.  12 hours, even if you been learning new skills all that time equates to 2, maybe 3 DAYS of real world experience.  You want to get some real projects under your belt before returning back to the recruiter.

Try taking the technology, building a real app (base on something real, this isn't about requirements, it's you learning the real world compromises to build), try and incorporate functionality that will be of interest to a company you want to pitch to, publish it on something like github, and you have something to demo/chat about/demonstrate what you've learned.

Then go to the recruiters and get your job.

Comment: Sounds ideal. Thanks, I was thinking the same, but the position came up quickly. I would try to do it soon.!

Answer (score 1):

You could email the recruiter about this, but what are they after? Are they after someone who has completed a 12 hour online course or are they after someone who has confidence around large production systems?

I would suggest that you build a web application that has a major focus on front end code where perhaps the server side is handling only the database connection.

Building an usable real world application will put you easily into a position where you will be able to tackle the role with confidence.

I started with some of these 12 hour online courses, but after building several medium sized fully functional web applications, I can tell you that there is a sea of difference in two candidates, one with 12 hours, and another with production experience.

But that's ok, many roles only ask for someone with little experience. Getting a job is all about knowing the role you're applying for and doing that research.

If you're research into the role shows that they are after someone with 12 hours Javascript experience, feel free to email them with your updated experience and credentials.

Some Jobs will take you with 0 hours.

Good luck!

Comment: Makes sense, I was thinking of the same lines but did feel that I should update them before too late. They are after 2 years experienced developers and I have 3 years in non JS production level development experience.

Comment: The 3 years in non JS development, that counts for something. Reading over my post again I think I was mainly aiming it at someone who has little production experience in general, that's my bad I should have clarified. If you have for example, 3 years in PHP production experience, use that to your advantage. (I'm all for hiring programming language agnostic as long as the candidate is experienced with real work applications.)